# VLOOKUP returns N/A when lookup column contains nested formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I've looked through the large number of "VLOOKUP"-relate questions, and can't seem to find a similar issue.

My lookup table's search column has data formatted like this:

```
HT100
HT101
HT102
```

But these values are formula based, where the original values were:

```
HT100 - a sweet truck
HT101 - another sweet truck
etc.
```

So the lookup table's search column actually contains the following formula:

```
=LEFT(A2,5)
```

where A2 refers to the full version of the data

The problem arises, however, when I get to a small subset of the data that looks like this:

```
LDR100 - a sweet front-end loader
```

Because it's 6 characters long, I can't use the formula above.  Instead, I started using:

```
=LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1))
```

This chops the string at the first space character.

Problem:

VLOOKUP will return a match if the data is formatted "HT100".

VLOOKUP will return a match if the data is formatted "LEFT(A2,5)".

VLOOKUP will NOT return a match if the data is formatted "LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1))

My questions is: Why does VLOOKUP fail to return a match when the second argument of LEFT() is not a constant?

Comment: Note: VLOOKUP also fails to return a match if I put the second argument of LEFT() in another column and reference it, such as `=LEFT(A2,G2)` where G2 is a cell that contains the number 5 or 6 (as required)

Comment: Your `LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1))` formula is leaving a space at the end of the results.  Change the formula to `=trim(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1)))`

Comment: @ScottCraner it's as easy as that.  Using `=LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1)-1)` also works.  Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because you include space in your lookup value.
Try this:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2, SEARCH(" ",A2,1)**-1**),$B$2:$C$4,2,FALSE)
```

or try not exact match:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2, SEARCH(" ",A2,1)-1),$B$2:$C$4,2,**TRUE**)
```

Comment: See comments on the original question.  Your first answer is the same as what I mention and functionally the same as what Scott Craner suggests, but in general I dislike using "TRUE" in VLOOKUP for applications like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues in the past. A quick work-around would be to copy the values to a new column and perform the Vlookup.

Hope this helps!